# shell_exec and vlc issues?

Tags: php, server, streaming, vlc

I'm making a streaming server with the CLI vlc. To make this easier, I made a WEB control interface using HTML/PHP.  The problem is when I run the following command in a terminal it works perfectly, but when launch it from PHP it fails (it makes like there was no options after vlc).

```
> vlc -vvv movie.mp4 --sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554} --sout-keep
```

Here is my PHP file:

```php
<?php
    $output = shell_exec($_POST['command']);
    echo $output;
?>
```

Input file:

```html
<form method="POST" action="textearea.php">
    <textarea  id="command" name="command"> 
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
```

the `$output` variable says that:

> VLC media player 2.2.4 Weatherwax Command Line Interface initialized. Type help for help. > Shutting down.

It is exactly the same as if I just typed `vlc` in the terminal by itself - and of course, the stream doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the answer by myself. you just need to replace vlc by cvlc in the command. it's a right problem of the www-data user.